# Redirect on login, doing it wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

On login, my magento 1.9 site is redirecting to a specific product

Specifically, when a user logs in from the login page, from the checkout page, any login I have been able to test always goes to the same individual product

It happens in live and in beta (i can print out or console log to beta without customers being affected)

I have no mod/plugin/addon designed to redirect user on login. I have redirect off (to profile page) in the admin back-end

I really just need to know where to look in the code for what is happening... I have done a grep search for `setBeforeAuthUrl` and `$this->_redirect`, along with a few other choice terms (including the key and id of the product and product category)

Comment: Please open file for `Mage_Customer_AccountController` and put some log or exit in this functions `loginPostAction` and `_loginPostRedirect`. Try to debug from there only.

Comment: check if there is any rewrite rule you added by mistake.

Comment: NalinSavaliya - will add a log, thank you for the location
---
KalyanChakravarthiV - wouldn't a rewrite affect every time a page load is attempted?  So every time I loaded checkout, I would redirect?  This occurs every time I login, i am supposed to go to the previous page, but instead am sent to the same product page no matter where you login from (login succeeds)